# Play! - how to reuse common logic for path fragment

Tags: java, model-view-controller, playframework

I am currently using **Play 2.3** and I have to deal with similar URL mappings:

```
GET /api/companyId/employeeId/tasks
GET /api/companyId/employeeId/timesheets
etc.
```

In every GET I need to perform similar logic:

```
public Promise<Result> getEmployeeTimesheets(Long companyId, Long employeeId) {
    return promise(() -> {
        if (!companyRepository.one(companyId).isPresent()) {
            return notFound("Company doesn't exist");
        }
        if (!employeeRepository.one(employeeId).isPresent()) {
            return notFound("Employee doesn't exist");
        }
        if (!employeeRepository.employeeWorksForCompany(companyId, employeeId)) {
            return forbidden("Employee doesn't work for this company");
        }

        // some actual logic here
    });
}
```

This code repeats over and over again. So far I used plain old **inheritance** and moved that repeating code into the parent controller class. It gets the job done, but it certainly isn't perfect solution (because I have to invoke parent method and inspect results manually in every controller action).

Is there some more declarative approach in Play that would automatically handle fragment of URL (`/api/companyId/employeeId` in our case) and either delegate the execution to an appropriate controller, or return an error response (for example 404 - Not Found).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you are calling the method again and again in each controller function instead you can use `@With` annotation.For ex

create a class **CheckUrl.java**

```
public class CheckUrl extends play.mvc.Action.Simple {

    public F.Promise<SimpleResult> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {

        String host = request().uri();

         if (condition one satisfied) {

             return F.Promise.pure(redirect("/someurl"));

        }else if (condition two satisfied){

         return F.Promise.pure(redirect(controllers.routes.SomeController.index()));

        }

}
```

Place `@With(CheckUrl.class)` in class to apply to all its function.

```
@With(CheckUrl.class)
public class MyController extends Controller {

}
```

and for a particular function

```
public class MyController extends Controller {
    @With(CheckUrl.class)
    public static Result index() {
     }

}
```

In the above cases CheckUrl.java is invoked before function in a controller

Comment: I ended up using @With approach, but there was a minor caveat; I had to parse path parameters from the URL manually :-/